# What are the running times of these?

Tags: arrays, linked-list, time-complexity, big-o

I need to compare the worst case running time of a linked list vs an array.

If ordering must be preserved and the list/array already has n items, what will be the worst case running times for the following? And why?

These are the questions and my answers:

```
Adding an item to the front of a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1)
Adding an item to the front of a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)

Accessing the (n/2):th item of a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)
Accessing the (n/2):th item of a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1)

Deleting the (n/2):th item from a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1) - CORRECT ANSWER O(n)
Deleting the (n/2):th item from a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding an item to the front of a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1)

To add an element at the beginning of a list, you need to change some pointers only. So, its complexity is `O(1)`.

> Adding an item to the front of a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)

In an array, to add an element at the beginning(or in the middle), all the elements stored after that index need to be shifted by one position. So, it takes `O(n)` in the worst case.

> Accessing the (n/2):th item of a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)

To access an element in a linked list, you need to traverse it from the beginning using next pointers as they are not contiguous in memory. So, it takes `O(n)` time.

> Accessing the (n/2):th item of a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1)

Arrays are contiguous in memory. So, you can access the `i`th element using index in `O(1)` time.

All the answers except this one are correct.

> Deleting the (n/2):th item from a linked list. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(1)

Deleting the (n/2) th element is `O(n)` because access time of (n/2) th element is not `O(1)`. You need to traverse until half of the array which is a `O(n)` operation.

> Deleting the (n/2):th item from a standard array. ANSWER ATTEMPT: O(n)

Just as in the case of adding, you need to copy over the elements after the deleted index one step forward. So, it takes `O(n)` time.

Comment: How would I explain the others?

Comment: Worth noting that all the other answers are correct

Comment: @user161151, like is add() for linked lists O(1) because no elements need to be shifted downwards and add() for arrays O(n) because elements need to be shifted downwards?

Comment: @user161151 and for accessing, linked-lists are not index and arrays are index right? also for deleting, why is it O(n) for arrays?